# My new theme doesn't show the slogan

Tags: theming

My site has a nice slogan that was shown with the previous theme.

Now, after installing the new theme "Nexus" ([Live demo here](http://nexus.techsaran.com/)), the slogan appears no longer. What should be done to make it appear again? thx.

Comment: Have a look in the theme settings to see if it's a feature you need to enable. http://nexus.techsaran.com/admin/appearance/settings/nexus

Comment: I'm sorry, it tells me "Access denied"... I can't see this page... :|

Comment: You'll need to login. Then go to Admin > Appearance > Settings and click on the name of your theme in the tabs.

Comment: Oh already checked that. anyways the problem is PHP based. The guys didn't create a relevant PHP segment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call it a bug in Nexus theme.

If you sub-themed Nexus, copy the page.tpl.php from Nexus templates folder into your sub-theme's template folder, then make the following change to the copied file, just after the h1 tag for the title:

```
// look for this
<h1 id="site-title">
  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>"><?php print $site_name; ?></a>
</h1>
// then add this below it
<?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
  <div id="site-slogan">
    <?php print $site_slogan; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```